# Paginate Result from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to paginate the result from thinking sphinx in rails console without any pagination gem. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, it is possible.](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/searching.html#pagination) Thinking Sphinx does not require any pagination gems… you can either use the `:per_page` and `:page` options in a search request:

```
# page: the page of results, defaults to 1 (the first page).
# per_page: number of results in each set, defaults to 20.
Article.search "pancakes", :page => 2, :per_page => 50
```

These are the same options as WillPaginate - and the resulting search results object can be used with the WillPaginate view helper - but *you do not need* WillPaginate to use these options.

There is also the possibility to use the `per_page` method on a search results object, like with Kaminari - but again, Kaminari is not required (even though the search results object can also be used with Kaminari's view helper):

```
articles = Article.search("pancakes")
articles.per_page(10)
```

There is also the `:offset` option, if you wish to calculate the number of results to skip (rather than using `:page` and `:per_page` to automate such calculations).